# How to navigate with arrows in a multi-line list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of images varying in length, and I want to display them in two rows like the image below is showing.

I can do this using flex-wrap or similar.

The trick is that I need to navigate with the arrows in an intuitive way. Going left to right is easy because I would just look for the next item in the list and set it to `active` while listening for the arrow keys to be pressed.

Where I'm stuck though, is vertical navigation. How would I handle it if I wanted to press the down arrow and go from block 3 to block 8? (Keep in mind that the length of this list is variable and won't always be an even number.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is a full row always 5 or is it flexible based on dimensions ? and are all the images shown with same width, or could an image occupy two widths in some row ?

Comment: Can't code up an example rn, but my approach would be to find the next element with the same x-coordinate as the currently active. Let's say you're on 3, you press "DOWN", then you go through each next sibling and focus the first one that lies on the same X-coordinate.

Comment: same with "UP", just that you iterate all prev siblings.this only works for strict grids, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the next element with the same X-coordinate as the currently active.

Let's say you're on 3, you press "DOWN", then you iterate through each next sibling, and focus the first one that lies on the same X-coordinate, which is 8 in your example.

This should work as long as the items are aligned in a grid.

Comment: This is a good solution.

In the end, I only needed two rows, so I displayed half the list on the top row, and then the other half in the row below it.

Then I kept track of the horizontal and vertical positions and adjusted accordingly.

Your solution works best for an undetermined amount of rows.